# Is there a way to create dataframes with a for loop using dpyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am using play-by-play NWHL data from [this wonderful resource](https://www.aklongmuir.com/nwhlbubble/data) to create dataframes for each team. However, I want to avoid having code repeat itself and want to do many actions using for loops. Here is the code that I have now...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)
library(dplyr)

#csvs <- c('2301', '2401', '2601', '2701', '3001', '3101', '0102')

D1 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-2301.csv')
D2 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-2401.csv')
D3 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-2601.csv')
D4 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-2701.csv')
D5 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-3001.csv')
D6 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-3101.csv')
D7 <- read_csv('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-0102.csv')

nwhl <- rbind(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7)

nwhl_teams = c('CTW', 'BUF', 'BOS', 'MIN', 'MET', 'TOR')
colors = c('BuGn', 'Blues', 'YlOrRd', 'BuPu', 'RdBu', 'RdGy')

for (team in nwhl_teams) {
  team <- df %>%
    filter(event_type %in% c('goal')) %>%
    filter(event_team == 'CTW') %>%
    group_by(event_player_1) %>%
    summarize(event_player_1, event_player_2, event_player_3, count = 1)
}

#CTW <- df %>%
#  filter(event_type %in% c('goal')) %>%
#  filter(event_team == 'CTW') %>%
#  group_by(event_player_1) %>%
#  summarize(event_player_1, event_player_2, event_player_3, count = 1)
```

The question I have is if there is a way to use the for loop to read csvs (using the csvs list) and is there a way to use a for loop for each item under the nwhl_teams list to create dataframes? Any assistance on this is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create all the url's of the csv with `sprintf` and use `map_df` to read each file and combind them into one dataframe. We create an `id` column to identify each individual csv.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

csvs <- c('2301', '2401', '2601', '2701', '3001', '3101', '0102')
urls <- sprintf('https://www.aklongmuir.com/s/NWHL2021-%s.csv', csvs)
data <- map_df(urls, readr::read_csv, .id = 'id')
data
```

You can then `filter` for `event_type = 'goal'` and all the `event_team` present in `nwhl_teams`.

```
nwhl_teams = c('CTW', 'BUF', 'BOS', 'MIN', 'MET', 'TOR')
colors = c('BuGn', 'Blues', 'YlOrRd', 'BuPu', 'RdBu', 'RdGy')

data %>% filter(event_type %in% 'goal', event_team %in% nwhl_teams)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out on this!

As of now, the first part of scraping the specific urls worked for me perfectly. 

However, I must have misspoke when it come to what I want in the second portion of my question. What I was hoping for was a for loop to get a dataframe for goal events for JUST nwhl_team CTW, then nwhl_team BUF, and so forth. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You can `split` the data after filtering. `list_data <- data %>% filter(event_type %in% 'goal', event_team %in% nwhl_teams) %>% split(.$event_team)`